# WiX DTF starts Windows Installer in classic look

Tags: c#, .net, wix, dtf

```
Installer.SetInternalUI(InstallUIOptions.Full);
Installer.InstallProduct("example.msi", "ACTION=INSTALL");
```

starts Windows Installer all right, but in Classic look and feel. The .msi itself looks all right when started standalone (it uses WiX's own provided UI). How could it be forced to start looking nice?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps, the screenshots might make it clearer...

Comment: Well, I thought Classic look is known enough after all these years but here it is. :-) This not only applies to the progress dialog but to all of the user interface later.

Answer (score 0):

"Classic look" isn't a Windows Installer term and I've never heard it used in relation to installers.  I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do and what your install looks like after this dialog but I would like to call out that you can logically OR InstallUIOptions arguments to get a combination such as Reduced UI and Hide Cancel ( this would be equiv to msiexec ... /qb! )

Comment: No, it isn't, it's a Windows term. See the screenshot above.

The UI itself and its functionality is all right, it works exactly as required and expected. The question was about the looks of the various interface elements. On Windows 7 with Aero look, the installer, when started as a standalone installer, uses the appropriate elements of the Windows Areo look (progress bar, buttons, etc). When it is started directly from the application, as described above, the same UI displays in what we usually call the Windows Classic look, with the old style progress bar, button, etc as shown above.